# Нарисованная фигура не соответствует заданным координатам

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

В общем, проблема такова, при нажатии на panel создается объект Block и происходит его отрисовка:

```
    private void DrawingPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point ptr = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        ptr.X -= DrawingPanelOffset.X;
        ptr.Y -= DrawingPanelOffset.Y;

        b = new Block(0, "Class", "Model", ptr);
        DrawingPanel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void DrawingPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (b != null)
            b.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
```

Непосредственно код блока

```
    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    { 
        Pen BlackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);      
        g.DrawRectangle(BlackPen,
                        Location.X,
                        Location.Y,
                        Location.X + 80,
                        Location.Y + 80);
    }
```

В итоге при нажатии на разные места панели получаются разные фигуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, фигуру растягивает и увеличивает в размере.
Что можно сделать, чтобы исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g.DrawRectangle(..., ..., ..., width, height);
```

то есть

```
g.DrawRectangle(BlackPen,
                    Location.X,
                    Location.Y,
                    80,
                    80);
```

Comment: Блин, просто привык, что в делфях передаются координаты начала и конца